# Call a model method on clicking a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am using Ruby on Rails for a project.

I have a couple of class objects with an attribute called `name`. The class of these objects is defined in the `models` folder. These objects are stored in a variable called `@objects`. I want to display a couple of links with the text as the text contained in the object's name attribute. So, if the objects are `@objects[1]`, `@objects[2]` and `@objects[3]`, I want to have

```
 <a href = "controller/action">@objects[1].name</a>
 <a href = "controller/action">@objects[2].name</a>
 <a href = "controller/action">@objects[3].name</a>
```

When I click on any one of these links, I want to execute a function present in the object's model class. So, on clicking the first link, I want to call `@objects[1].function()`; on clicking the second link, I want to call `@objects[2].function()` and so on.

I do not know how to send the object data to the controller. How do I specify the object whose function I want to call? Can't I directly call the method from the view and use the return value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use link_to and specify path for respective action

```
link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: This would execute the function before I click on the link. This executes the function and then creates the href based on the output. I do not want that. I want to execute the function when I click on the link.